# intellij zeppelin how to delete a paragraph?

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-zeppelin

I'm looking at [intellij-zeppelin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10023-intellij-zeppelin).  There is a movie there explaining how they delete a paragraph.  I'm not sure i followed as it's fast but it looks like he just delete the text line with the comment pointing to the paragraph.  I tried doing the same but the paragraph is not deleted in zeppelin.  Anything i'm missing?